# Mysql2::Error: Field 'handler' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, mysql2

Im upgrading my rails 3.22 app to 4.0.0 and got to some of my rspec test are faling with this error

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'handler' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs`
```

My schema file says

```
t.text     "handler",                   :null => false
```

I can see that is "a/the" problem but since this table is created by the gem and not me I dont how to deal with it?

Comment: Create a migration to (a) have a default value and (b) backfill previous entries? Or, e.g., https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/564, https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/945, etc.

Comment: Post as answer.. Added the protected attributes gem and it made it go away